# How to handle drop down menus using Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium, menu

I am trying to select an item from drop down menu after i open the page automatically with selenium.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("col-xs-6 bold text-right").text)
```

This is one of my codes tried to access the text. But it gives this error.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".col-xs-6 bold text-right"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

[image]

In this picture you can see which menu and which section i need to select item from.

NOTE** After the page in the picture just opened, when i click to look at the paths first it navigate me to `<body class="home"> == $0` when i click to look at the paths again it navigates me to `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you used to select the option in the drop down.

Comment: `selected = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]"))
selected.select_by_index(0)` or `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]").click()`

Comment: You need 2 clicks. One to open the drop down and another to click the item in the list.

Comment: But when i run the click section it gives me error. If you give me an example i would be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `"col-xs-6 bold text-right"` class selector doesn't match with the image attached.

Second, to select the drop-down menu items in selenium, you have to `click` the drop-down element first, and then menu-item.

Comment: Can you show me an example about this ? Because i am trying to click but it is not working.

Comment: Let me have the url and test credentials if needed.

Comment: Or you can let me have the HTML content so that I can test on my side.